# How to print text or an image in the header based on a control break

Tags: reporting-services, epicorerp

I am customizing our MICR check.  We often print hundreds of checks. Some of the checks pay many remit-to's and so the remit lines don't all fit on one page so there is overflow.  We need to print VOID over the check itself, which is in the HEADER on the second and subsequent pages for that check.

I wrote a visibility expression as follows:

=Iif(Globals!PageNumber > 1, False, True)

What that accomplished was hiding it on page 1 of the print job. The problem is that most pages after page 1 were new checks and shouldn't be voided. Only the second page from the same check should.
I need to do this on a control break where he check number changes. I should only print VOID when the current page has the same check number as the previous page. Since this is in the header, the check number refers to a hidden field in the body:

=reportitems!txtCalc_DspCheckNum21.value

I would compare this value to the previous check number but how do I store that previous check number and now compare the two?

I added a text box (very large letters) over the check and hid it.  I then

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to set this up using custom code.

In your Report Properties-Code page, insert the following code:

```
Dim LastCheck As String
Dim ThisCheck As String

Function SetCheck(CheckNumber As String) AS String
Begin
    LastCheck = ThisCheck
    ThisCheck = CheckNumber
    Return ThisCheck
End
```

Now for your Textbox `txtCalc_DspCheckNum21` give it the expression:

```
=Code!SetCheck(Fields!CheckNum.Value)
```

In your header, set the image Visiblility-Hidden expression to:

```
=IIF(Code.ThisCheck = Code.LastCheck, False, True)
```

So what we are doing is that whenever your Textbox `txtCalc_DspCheckNum21` gets rendered, it remembers the previous and current check numbers. If they are different (i.e. the first page for that cheque) it hides the image and if they are the same, it shows the VOID image (i.e. subsequent pages for that cheque).

Note that this relies on `txtCalc_DspCheckNum21` being rendered on every page.

Comment: As a compliment to Chris's solution from the epicor side of things, if i recall correctly i believe there is a way to increase the amount of lines that appear on each page for check stubs inside Epicor. This doesn't fix your problem, but helps minimize paper

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work: "The Visibility.Hidden expression for the text box ‘Textbox7’ includes the Previous aggregate function.  Previous cannot be used in page headers or footers."

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that in my quick answer. Let's try some custom code instead.

Comment: Thanks. That might work but I actually found an amazingly simple solution. If I select the row group that does the break, one of the properties is Group/PageBreak/ResetPageNumber. If I set that to TRUE it works!

Comment: Nice trick, well done! You should add that as an answer and accept it so future visitors to this question can use your solution.